# Laravel API controller returns 404 when hit through Twilio

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, twilio

I am trying to set up a route that I can let Twilio hit, that will return a response from Laravel.

But every Twilio request kicks back a `404 Http Response`.

Feels like I've got something misconfigured.

I have

1. Created ControllerClass `SmSController` with a `reply` method.
2. Added my route to `routes/api.php` to hit the controller.
3. Added my URL to the `$except` property in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

---

Here's my `app/Http/Controllers/SmsController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Twilio\Twiml;

class SmsController extends Controller
{
    public function reply(Request $request) {
        $response = new Twiml;
        $response->message("Hello World!");
        print $response;
    }
}

And Here's my `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function () {
    //
});
Route::post('sms/reply', 'SmsController@reply');
```

And inside the class `VerifyCsrfToken` I have:

```
protected $except = [
    'sms/reply'
];
```

*Edit: I should mention, I have Twilio to hit the URL: `https://www.MYWEBSITE.com/sms/reply`, which I think should correspond to the route I set up in `api.pip`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the routes inside of `api.php` are prefixed with `api` inside a url, so your `sms/reply` is actually `api/sms/reply`, does this make sense?

Comment: Oooh could it be that easy. Please hold, will try.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks so much Nikola : )